# Apply noise over mesh in OpenGL w/o texcoords

Tags: opengl, glsl, coordinates, textures, noise

I have an issue with applying noise over the surface of a non-trivial mesh (well any mesh) in OpenGL without texture coordinates. I basically want to have a noise texture applied over the surface but since I don't have texture coordinates I can't just apply a noise texture. Generating texture coordinates in the vertex shader works to an extent however whether it is cube, sphere or object planar coordinates there is always some texture smearing.

[smearing with cube map http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/3923/0ouu.png](http://img811.imageshack.us/img811/3923/0ouu.png)

Smearing with cube map coordinates across surface changes

[smearing with object planar http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/987/c3cz.png](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/987/c3cz.png)

Smearing with object planar (xy) coordinates along z plane

I've done random noise generation in the fragment shader however as this changes every frame it is not what i need (and not computationally cheap either).

I just need a static uniform distribution of noise across the mesh surface.

Anybody got any ideas on how this could be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could acquire 3d model space coordinates for each pixel in fragment shader and use some 3d noise based on those values.

Comment: Model space fragment coordinates is fine, and writing them to a Texture3D render target should be fine but can I just then sample that texture in another pass using the model space fragment coordinates?

Comment: My comment above may be a misunderstanding of what you meant in your answer. I think I understand what you mean now, instead of baking any of these values into a texture you mean calculating model space coordinates of each fragment and using a deterministic noise function each frame, that makes more sense, i'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Stinomus yes, that is what I was talking about.